# Pass props to a component in a Route at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have all of my Routes set up in App.js:

```
<main className="container my-4">
      <Route path='/sign-up' render={() => (
        <SignUp alert={this.alert} setUser={this.setUser} />
      )} />
      <Route path='/sign-in' render={() => (
        <SignIn alert={this.alert} setUser={this.setUser} />
      )} />
      <Route path='/info' render={() => (
        <Info alert={this.alert} />
      )} />
      <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
        <Redirect to='/home'/>
      )} />
      <Route exact path='/home' render={() => (
        <Home alert={this.alert} user={user}/>
      )} />
      <Route exact path='/schedule' render={() => (
        <Schedule alert={this.alert} user={user}/>
      )} />
```

In the Home component, there is a list of links that all contain certain scheduled dates. When a date is clicked, it links to “/schedule/:id” where :id is the id of the scheduled date. I want to pass different props to the Schedule component, based on what :id is. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `routeProps` to `render` and that'll allow you to pass different props to the components if you want to.

```js
<Route exact path='/schedule/:date' render={(routeProps) => (
  <Schedule alert={this.alert} user={user} date={routeProps.match.params.date} />
)} />
```

You can also hook a component up to a route.

```js
<Route exact path='/schedule/:date' component={Schedule} />
```

and this will give you access to match as well. If Schedule is class based, it would be accessed by `this.props.match.params.date`. If it were functional, it would be `props.match.params.date`. If you need to pass other props as well, the first example could be better.

### Edited in response to comment

If you need to pass an object from the `Schedule` component to another instance of the `Schedule` component through a [`Link` tag](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link), you can use an object within your `<Link to={{obj}}>Other Event</Link>`

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

The above is taken from the [react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link), but in your case, you could probably just use pathname and state:

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/schedule/${event.id}`,
    state: { event: this.state.event }
  }}
/>
```

And then you could access the `event` object within `Schedule` as `this.props.location.state.event`. Probably still some kinks to work out, but for those we'd have to take a look at the `Schedule` component itself. :)

Comment: I think my phrasing was a little confusing. Let’s say that the Schedule component gets all of the “events” from a REST Api endpoint and stores them in state. Then it renders a list of Link components (react router), one for each event that was returned from the API. And each link goes to a specific Event component at /schedule/:id. I want to pass the individual event object from state, to the component that will be rendered at /schedule/:id.

Comment: ah, thanks for that! Yeah, that is a bit different. Just edited my answer to address that situation. :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do. I didn’t know that you could use state in a Link. But then again it is a component so why not. Thank you!